# Next js ai SDK with google generative ai and langchain is causing edge runtime module not found error

Tags: next.js, next.js13, langchain-js, google-generativeai, edge-runtime

I am building a "chat with your document" chatbot using [Vercel AI SDK](https://sdk.vercel.ai/docs), [Nextjs 14](https://nextjs.org/) app router for the chat interface, [Google Generative AI](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/node_quickstart) for the chatbot and [Langchainjs](https://js.langchain.com/docs/get_started/introduction) to process the uploaded document (PDF to text parsing, splitting the text, create embeddings, saving it to a vector database and querying the embeddings to extract a context).

On user input, the `useChat` hooks will hit `POST /api/chat` api routes, and before sending the user-input to `genai`, i would first extract the context and build the `Message[]`

Without the `extract the context`, the app works just fine. But as soon as i add the context extraction, the console started to go crazy with the `Module not found` errors.

I browsed around for solutions, a lot of the solution suggested me to add a webpack config in my `nextjs.config.js` by adding `<module>: false` for the `config.resolve.fallback` for every module i found giving the errors, and i ended up with the following

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  ...
  webpack: (config, { webpack }) => {
    config.experiments = { ...config.experiments, topLevelAwait: true }
    config.externals['node:fs'] = 'commonjs node:fs'
    config.resolve.fallback = {
      ...config.resolve.fallback,
      fs: false,
      // buffer: false,
      crypto: false,
      // events: false,
      http: false,
      https: false,
      net: false,
      querystring: false,
      os: false,
      path: false,
      // querystring: false,
      stream: false,
      // tty: false,
      // util: false,
      zlib: false,
      tls: false,
      child_process: false,
    }
    config.plugins.push(
      new webpack.NormalModuleReplacementPlugin(
        /^node:/,
        (resource) => {
          resource.request = resource.request.replace(/^node:/, '')
        },
      ),
    )

    return config
  },
  ...
}
```

It doesn't give me the `Module not found error` anymore, instead its giving me this error

```
⨯ node_modules/gaxios/node_modules/agent-base/dist/index.js (33:0) @ <unknown>
⨯ Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

This might be caused by a React Class Component being rendered in a Server Component, React Class Components only works in Client Components. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/class-component-in-server-component
```

At this point, i have no idea what to fix and where should i fix it, and i got a feeling that is not an optimal solution.

From the errors i can tell that what's causing this is mostly the `@langchain/community` packages, i have also browse around solutions related to the edge-runtime and langchain with no luck, please help